# Do incapacitated soldiers with bleeding wounds need any extra care?

Tags: xenonauts

In my ground squad's latest outing, I lost a trooper to a shot that left her with 1 hitpoint - and a bleeding wound, which incapacitated her at the beginning of my next turn.

I know that the more HP dealt to the soldier over their maximum, the more likely they are to die. But does bleeding factor in here? Do hitpoints continue dropping further into the negatives after the trooper is downed? And can a medikit even be used to heal an incapacitated squaddie?

Answer (score 2):

On wikia, about [bleeding](http://xenonauts.wikia.com/wiki/Bleeding)

> For every bleeding wound a unit is suffering from, they will lose 5 HP
>   every turn. For example. if a soldier is suffering from two bleeding
>   wounds, they will lose 10 HP every turn. Every time a soldier is hit
>   by a weapon, there is a flat 20% chance that they will suffer from a
>   bleeding wound, neither armour nor cover mitigates this percentage
>   chance.
>
> All bleeding wounds can be healed with a Medipack, at least 5 HP must
>   be healed for the bleeding wound to be healed.

And about [Soldier Recovery](http://xenonauts.wikia.com/wiki/Soldier_Recovery)

> Once the battle is over, a calculation is preformed on all dead
>   soldiers to determine if they survived their wounds or not. In order
>   for a soldier to be eligible for this the following conditions must be
>   met.
>
> Their body must have been recovered, this happens either if the
>   Xenonauts win the battle, or the corpse is on the dropship when the
>   mission is aborted. They must not have suffered below -20 health
>   damage. So if a Soldier with 40hp was hit by a plasma bolt that dealt
>   70 damage, this would reduce their damage to -30, meaning they are
>   truly dead and have no chance of recovering. The calculation to
>   determine if a soldier survives is: chance = B + C * HP
>
> B represents the soldiers base percentage chance of recovery, which by
>   default is 50. C represents how much the percentage value will
>   decrease for every point of health below 0, by default this number is
>   set to 2.5.

Therefore, in your case, she will be incapacitated with -4 hp.
The chance is 50 - 2.5%*4 = 40% she will survive.

Comment: These quotes don't mention anything about whether or not bleeding damage continues to be accumulated after HP reaches 0, which is the primary thrust of the question.

Comment: In game, I found no clue if troop continues taking bleeding damage after incapacitated.

Comment: The first part about -20 being the cutoff is redundant with the formula, since 100 - 50 - (2.5 * 20) = 0% anyway.  It is also a 0% chance *at* -20, not below -20 as you mentioned.